# Ember.js REST adapter handling different JSON structure

Tags: javascript, api, rest, ember.js, ember-data

I'm using REST adapter, when I call `App.Message.find()` Ember.js makes call to the `/messages` to retrieve all messages and expect to see JSON structure like this:

```
{
    "messages": [] // array contains objects
}
```

However API I have to work with response always with:

```
{
    "data": [] // array contains objects
}
```

I only found the way1 to change [namespace or URL](http://emberjs.com/guides/models/the-rest-adapter/#toc_endpoint-path-customization) for the API. **How to tell REST adapter to look for `data` instead of `messages` property?**

*If this is not possible how to solve this problem? CTO said we can adapt API to use with REST adapter as we want, but from some reason we can't change this `data` property which will be on each response.*

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are ok with writing your own adapter to deal with the difference, in the success callback you can simply modify the incoming name from "data" to your specific entity -in the case above "messages"

I do something like this to give you and idea of what if possible in a custom adapter

In the link below I highlighted the return line from my findMany

The json coming back from my REST api looks like

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "score": 2,
        "feedback": "abc",
        "session": 1
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "score": 4,
        "feedback": "def",
        "session": 1
    }
]
```

I need to transform this before ember-data gets it to look like this

```
{
    "sessions": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "score": 2,
            "feedback": "abc",
            "session": 1
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "score": 4,
            "feedback": "def",
            "session": 1
        }
    ]
}
```

https://github.com/toranb/ember-data-django-rest-adapter/blob/master/packages/ember-data-django-rest-adapter/lib/adapter.js#L56-57

```
findMany: function(store, type, ids, parent) {
    var json = {}
    , adapter = this
    , root = this.rootForType(type)
    , plural = this.pluralize(root)
    , ids = this.serializeIds(ids)
    , url = this.buildFindManyUrlWithParent(store, type, ids, parent);

    return this.ajax(url, "GET", {
      data: {ids: ids}
    }).then(function(pre_json) {
      json[plural] = pre_json; //change the JSON before ember-data gets it
      adapter.didFindMany(store, type, json);
    }).then(null, rejectionHandler);
},
```